# how to numerate java enum in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, enums

I have enum class Role. I want to store this values in mysql DB in the table roles.

```
public enum Role {
ADMIN,
USER,
TRAINER
}
```

table roles

```
id          role
1           ADMIN
2           USER
3           TRAINER
```

I use following code for table mapping

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
```

table users

```
create TABLE users(
id INTEGER UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(20),
password VARCHAR(20),
registered TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now(),
role_id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
enabled BOOL DEFAULT TRUE,
FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles(id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

But in Java enum ordinal numbers start from 0, so 0 = ADMIN, 1 = USER, 2 = TRAINER and when i try to set user Role.ADMIN i receive an exception because there are no elements in DB with such number (0).

Comment: Change the id to 0-based in mysql.

Comment: @Taylor As for me Id=0 looks strange. Can I save current numeration in DB?

Comment: Java is 0-based, there is no way to change this.  Trying to fight this can lead to very snarly bugs, I'd recommend just rolling with 0-based.

Comment: Use an attribute converter: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/